# AES128 encryption/decryption in swift frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, swift

Im writing a swift framework and I need to use AES128 Encryption and decryption. I cannot use Objective c since we can't use bridging headers inside swift framework. Anybody knows how to do this with pure swift?

Comment: Just use CCCrypt from Swift, it is not Objective-C. It is not that difficult. Try, post your code if there are problems along with test data, results and an explanation of the problems. SO is not a service to write code.

Comment: @Zaph: Using CommonCrypto requires using a bridging header (it's not part of any Cocoa frameworks), which the OP can't use.

Comment: Perhaps using Swift was not the best idea.